# i need to give space in title description

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I need to give space in the title description means where the title end next para will start after the title space below I am creating Reactjs application like see in the image below.

```
                   <p title={props.selectedEntity.address}>
                      <strong>
                        {" "}
                        {props.selectedEntity.search_type === "individual"
                          ? "Address :"
                                : "N/A"}
                      </strong>
                      {' '}{props.selectedEntity.search_type === "individual"
                        ? props.selectedEntity.address
                          ? props.selectedEntity.address
                          : "N/A"}
                    </p>
```

Comment: Can you share the code what you done so far?

Comment: check code i added

Answer (score -1):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. With the help of flex property, you can set title and description as per your requirement

Please refer to this link:
https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/4u3vkewt/7/

```css
p {
  width: 216px;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
}

p strong {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p title={props.selectedEntity.address}>
  <strong>
    Address
  </strong>
  this is long Address this is long Address this is long Address
</p>
```

Comment: We have updated our answer as per your requirement.

Answer (score -2):

You can achieve it by wrapping title and paragraph in div, then adding (display:flex) style to div.

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>title</h1>
  <p>paragraph</p>
</div>
```

In css file:

```
.container{
  width: ;   //specify width for this to work
  display:flex;
  align-items:flex-start;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
```